# Character encoding via Rest API/JSON

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, utf8-decode

From a RestAPI method call I am getting following JSON output (this is a JSON output from Socialcast RestAPI).

```
{
   "message":{
      "id":18755210,
      "user":{
         "id":964633,
         "name":"Lasith Chandrasekara",
         "url":"https://searchtechnologies-com.socialcast.com/users/964633-lasithchandrasekara",
      },
      "title":"",
      "body":"\"\u0db8\u0dad\u0dca \u0d9a\u0dd4\u0da9\u0dd4 \u0d9a\u0db1\u0dca\u0da7\u0dda\u0db1\u0dbb\u0dba \u0dc3\u0db8\u0dca\u0db6\u0db1\u0dca\u0db0 \u0dc3\u0dd2\u0daf\u0dca\u0db0\u0dd2\u0dba\u0dda\u0daf\u0dd3 \u0d85\u0d9c\u0db8\u0dd0\u0dad\u0dd2\u0dc0\u0dba\u0dcf\u0d9c\u0dda \u0dbb\u0dd9\u0daf\u0dca\u0daf \u0d9a\u0dd0\u0d9e\u0dd3 \u0db1\u0dd2\u0dbb\u0dd4\u0dc0\u0dad \u0db4\u0dda\u0db1\u0dca\u0db1\u0dda \u0da2\u0dcf\u0dad\u0dd2\u0d9a \u0dc4\u0dd9\u0dc5 \"",
      "action":""
   }
}
```

I want to process this with java and pass to another system called "save2xml" (which is another java component that take this as a input and save this input as a xml file).

The part of output of savet2xml file as follows.

```
<body>\"\u0db8\u0dad\u0dca \u0d9a\u0dd4\u0da9\u0dd4 \u0d9a\u0db1\u0dca\u0da7\u0dda\u0db1\u0dbb\u0dba \u0dc3\u0db8\u0dca\u0db6\u0db1\u0dca\u0db0 \u0dc3\u0dd2\u0daf\u0dca\u0db0\u0dd2\u0dba\u0dda\u0daf\u0dd3 \u0d85\u0d9c\u0db8\u0dd0\u0dad\u0dd2\u0dc0\u0dba\u0dcf\u0d9c\u0dda \u0dbb\u0dd9\u0daf\u0dca\u0daf \u0d9a\u0dd0\u0d9e\u0dd3 \u0db1\u0dd2\u0dbb\u0dd4\u0dc0\u0dad \u0db4\u0dda\u0db1\u0dca\u0db1\u0dda \u0da2\u0dcf\u0dad\u0dd2\u0d9a \u0dc4\u0dd9\u0dc5 \"</body>
```

How can I get decoded string (like follows) with the output of save2xml?
"මත් කුඩු කන්ටේනරය සම්බන්ධ සිද්ධියේදී අගමැතිවයාගේ රෙද්ද කැඞී නිරුවත පේන්නේ ජාතික හෙළ "

Note:
I debugged the save2xml component as follows and it print encoding as cp1252.

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
    getLogger().info("XXXXXXX ecndoing is " + out.getEncoding());
```

So here I don't want to change save2xml component. What I can do is process JSON and do whatever modification before passing to the save2xml component. Please advice the change I have to done when processing the JSON to get decoded (readable) output in xml.

I guess the JSON is in UTF-8.

Comment: Use a JSON parser - e.g. [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome)

Comment: JSON parser is used and created object from JSON. But how to process the encoding? I don't have problem with JSON. Only problem I want to solve is encoding.

Comment: If you want to write Unicode, [specify an encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) when you create your OutputStreamWriter. If you're still having problems, say what JSON parser you are using and how you're writing your XML.

Comment: Ok, so lets forge about JSON and say we have string like "\"\u0db8\u0dad\u0dca \u0d9a\u0dd4\u0da9\u0dd4 \u0d9a\u0db1\u0" ... So how can I get readable output like  "මත් කුඩු කන්ටේ" . from previous encoded string. Also I dont have a way to change the writing of XML. As I mentioned save2xml component uses encoding cp1252